# What is my AWS EC2 SPF TXT Record?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, server

I try to create my Own email server on my Instance. I installed MailEnable. I added all records in Domain dns except spf. After configured then I sent a mail to gmail. It was ok I received mail to my Gmail account. But I ry to send mail from Gmail to my email. This case I didn't received any email. I think i missed spf configuration. I have elastic ip of my EC2 instance. Now what is should be my spf record?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general email/server tech support.

Comment: @MarcB, and this is a programming question. BTW, this site is to answer programming questions, and not explaining people who you are

Comment: spf records aren't programming. that's server configuration.

Comment: Sorry that was my first question in here, kind of mistake to switching site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're not to familiar with SPF Records, in that cause you'll want to use and [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/) to generate the record for you. You'll go through a questionnaire and at the end it will produce the record for you.

Comment: I saw that but I tried that one previously, not worked.

Comment: Can you post your domain and your SPF record?

Comment: I try to setup mail enable for my Instance, I did domain verified on amazon SES.

Comment: Well you spf is completely wrong, change it to "v=spf1 mx a ~all". Is your mail server running on reborngaming.xyz? If it is, that SPF should work.